# Juju local / add-machine / lxc: How to specify hostname of new lxc-machine

Tags: juju, lxc

Is it possible to specify hostname (and machine-name) when creating a new lxc machine in juju-local?

For excample, after a fresh juju local bootstrap, execute:

```
juju add-machine
```

This will create a new lxc-machine named **user01-local-machine-1** (where user01 is the currently logged user)

**Question:** Is there a way to specify a custom name (instead the of the auto-generaterd **user01-local-machine-1**) for the created machine?

For reference, my enviornment-yaml file is following:

```
default: local
environments:
    local:
        type: local
        root-dir: /data00/juju-env/juju-local
        network-bridge: lxcbr0
        default-series: trusty
        enable-os-refresh-update: true
```

Juju version is: **1.24.5-vivid-amd64**

Thanks.